# Defining a function with a subscripted head

Tags: function-construction, subscript

How can I define a function with subscript?

Forexample:

```
f_alpha[x] = 2*x
```

Comment: `Subscript[f, a][x_] := (* stuff *)`?

Comment: Or if `a` is also variable: `Subscript[f, a_][x_] := (* other stuff *)`

Comment: However, `f[a_][x_]  :=  (* other stuff *)` will turn out to be more tractable for serious computation.